# List specific files on a remote windows machine from a linux machine using sftp

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sftp

working a script that lists or outputs specific files on a windows machine directory when executed a script from a Linux server

Here is the current script we got, it lists all contents in the windows directory but my requirement is to filter out the required ones

```
echo "ls -l ${TARGET_ICT_DIR}\nquit\n" | sftp ${SFTP_LOGIN} | tee /tmp/ver_ict_rel_dest_${L_CURR_PID}.txt
```

The above command outputs all files in that windows directory but im looking for files that only searches below files:

```
anchor.jar
rename.txt
zipper.dat
```

Please suggest

Comment: echo "ls -l {anchor.jar,rename.txt,zipper.dat
} ${TARGET_ICT_DIR}\nquit\n" | sftp ${SFTP_LOGIN} | tee /tmp/ver_ict_rel_dest_${L_CURR_PID}.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this insertion of **grep** in the pipeline do the trick?

```
echo "ls -l ${TARGET_ICT_DIR}\nquit\n" |
    sftp ${SFTP_LOGIN} |
    grep -E ' (anchor\.jar|rename\.txt|zipper.dat)\r?$' |
    tee /tmp/ver_ict_rel_dest_${L_CURR_PID}.txt
```

Do not know if the check for \r is necessary -- but... Windows...  Also, in comment *@ghoti* noted that `\r` might not translate well to all versions of **grep** and shell.  You could try something like the following if you run into such:

```
echo "ls -l ${TARGET_ICT_DIR}\nquit\n" |
    sftp ${SFTP_LOGIN} |
    grep -E " (anchor\.jar|rename\.txt|zipper.dat)$(printf '\r')?$" |
    tee /tmp/ver_ict_rel_dest_${L_CURR_PID}.txt
```

*(Both variants of the `ls -l | grep -E ...` part was tested with **dash** and **bash** on Linux.)*

Comment: Might want to switch that to `egrep`. From [`man re_format`](http://man.freebsd.org/re_format): ***Obsolete (''basic'') regular expressions differ in several respects. '|' is an ordinary character and there is no equivalent for its functionality.*** The option to use it escaped in `grep` is I think a GNUism that may not be portable to `grep` on other platforms.

Comment: **grep** uses standard regular expressions which is equivalent to extended.  But, you are right that this looks a little backslash happy.  I'll add the **egrep** as an option...

Comment: In fact, `grep` uses BRE notation by default; that's the whole point of having `egrep` around. Check your man page. If you're on a Linux system, see the description of the `-G` option. "This is the default." But don't assume everyone is running Linux or using GNU grep. While the question may have mentioned Linux in its subject, part of the value of an answer is in its portability. And if your answer depends on a particular version of a tool (as yours does), it's best to mention that limitation in the answer itself.

Comment: Noted -- I'll use grep -E to be explicit.

Comment: Great. Only one gotcha left, which is the `\r`. Format characters are not part of BRE *or* ERE. If your shell is bash, you might be able to get away with format substitution, i.e. `$' (..|..|..)\r?$'`, but this notation is not part of a POSIX regular expression. Compare `printf 'one\r\ntwo\n' | grep -E '\r' | od -c` to `printf 'one\r\ntwo\n' | grep -E $'\r' | od -c`.

Answer (score 0):

i used below one and it satisfied my condition

```
echo "ls -l {anchor.jar,rename.txt,zipper.dat} ${TARGET_ICT_DIR}\nquit\n" | sftp ${SFTP_LOGIN} | tee /tmp/ver_ict_rel_dest_${L_CURR_PID}.txt
```